# Filter data from Several Tables and insert into a temp table

Tags: php, html, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Suppose we have data required for email broadcast in several tables and we need to uses some common fields information like (Name, Email)  from different tables into a temp table for email broadcast etc..
Table Eaxmples
`Employee`, `Student`, `Class`, `Parents` tables etc

Let us say we need to send emails to for difference scenarios

1. All Student
2. Grade 5 Students only
3. Employee only
4. Parents Only
5. Employee, Parents
6. Grade 3, Grade 5, Grade 6 students only

We can have several combination. I have been thinks about this a searched for similar examples but could not find any related example.

Sample Table structure

```
Employee/Teacher (ID, Name, Email, Phone..)
Student (ID,Name,Email,Phone..)
Class(ID,ClassName)
Subject (ID, SubjectName, GradeID)
Parent(ID,Name,Email,Phone...)
```

I would appreciate a pointer or an approach that we cant take, Biggest question is how to generat dynamic query for this so that relevant data from different table can be selected for sending emails notifications or intimations etc.

Comment: I think this question needs more detail before anyone can provide truly useful help. Why are you using a temp table?  Are you going to be querying the collection of tables one time to gather the list of email recipients? Can you run separate queries for different types of recipients? When you say dynamic query, do you mean dynamic SQL? Is dynamic SQL a requirement?

Comment: so many irrelevant tags.

Comment: @DCaugs, I may not require temp table, if i can generate dynamic queries based on the user selection. Selection can vary from time to time, I may have not explained it clearly. in simple words i want to know how can we get email,Name,PhoneNo from different tables based of scenarios mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Kritner, I need this actually for asp.net mvc project and i wanted to include php users also as they could also point me to a logic to select data from different tables

Answer (score 1):

This really boils down to application architecture more than data structure, though you could possibly improve the data structure as well, from the looks of those tables.

Ultimately, you are presenting your end user with options to access data. You need to narrow their choices down as far as possible on the front end before sending the request into your database tables. The more narrow you can make their final request, the more simple your database queries will be.

Building multiple dynamic SQL queries may be an option. This is more difficult to work with initially, but will most likely procure the most efficient, narrow execution plans each time they are called.

Calls to table-focused stored procs would be another approach - e.g. the user requests all teacher and all parent email addresses on the front end, which in turn calls a teacher table focused proc and a separate parent table focused proc with the appropriate parameters, and returns the data to the front end.

At the end of the day, simplify your data structure if possible (combine users into a single user table rather than multiple, redundant storage of user type data across multiple tables. More about normal form in databases [here](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm)), narrow the flexibility on your front end queries as much as is practical, and be ready to tweak and tune as you discover end user access patterns which don't line up with your initial query design.

There are a lot of variables and no silver bullets, unfortunately. That being said, identifying the *specific* problem you are trying to solve, and then asking yourself *why* it is a problem to begin with, will get you pretty far down the road to a solution.